Lookup vault keys in hcl?
I am refactoring a Nomad job's HCL so that my developers can run it on their own machines instead of some central server. Currently I have this block:
    ...
    task "internal-task" {
      artifact {
        source      = "git::git@github.com:Corporation/internal-tool.git"
        destination = "local/internal_tool"
        options {
            sshkey = "${base64encode(file("/etc/nomad.d/ssh/internal_tool_ssh_key"))}"
        }
      }
      ...

The problem is that sshkey line, it assumes there is a file in a specific spot since this job is normally run from a central server.
I want my developers to just run this on their laptops, so I put the SSH key in our Vault instance. I want to lookup the key from Vault using a function similar to file( above, like this:
sshkey = "${base64encode(vault_lookup("/vault/path/to/ssh/key/secret"))}"

Does such a function exist, or what are my options?
